# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH. when doing update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to submit for updating the data, i already use the `patch` method, but it keep telling me that `the get method is not supported`

the edit form**edit.info.blade**

```
 <form action="{{ route('info.update', ['info' => $info->id]) }}" method="patch" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

the route list
**web.php**

```
//info penting
route::get('/info-admin','InfosController@index')->middleware('auth','admin')->name('admin.info-admin');
route::get('/tambah-info','PagesController@tambah')->middleware('auth','admin')->name('info.add');

route::patch('/update-info/{info}/update','InfosController@update')->name('info.update');
route::get('/edit-info/{info}/edit','InfosController@edit')->middleware('auth','admin')->name('info.edit');


route::delete('/info/{id}','InfosController@destroy')->middleware('auth','admin')->name('info.destroy');
```

here's for update logic
**InfosController**

```
public function update(Request $request, Info $info) {
    Info::where('id', $info->id)->update([
        'judul' => $request->judul,
        'konten' => $request->konten,
        'image' => $request->image,
    ]);
    return redirect('')->route('admin.info-admin')->with('success', 'Successful');
}
```

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5 forms only supports `GET`, `POST` and `DIALOG` method only. so using `PATCH` won't work.

you have to add it inside the from

```
<form action="{{ route('info.update', ['info' => $info->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
@method('PATCH')
```

this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) will help you to understand form methods.

Comment: so it's like alravel trying to add their method forcefully into our browser huh?

Comment: no, they all are HTTP methods. but browsers only support those methods to submit a form.

Comment: i see, i get it now

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the method to `POST`.  Because in some browser PUT/PATCH is not suported

```
 <form action="{{ route('info.update', ['info' => $info->id]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

           <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: and now i got this ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::route()```

Comment: @Harmoning it is because ` return redirect()` you are passing a empty string to redirect method

Comment: ah its already fixed, just need to change it to ```return redirect('/info-admin')->with('success', 'Successful')```